# Having trouble compiling my code in the remix IDE

Tags: solidity

Trying to code a rocks, paper, scissors game, but having trouble getting the contract code to compile:

Current error I am getting is: ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier -->

I think I'm missing a { or ) somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 */
contract Game {

    uint8 constant ROCK = 0;
    uint8 constant PAPER = 1;
    uint8 constant SCISSORS = 2;
    address[] public players;

    // the public keyword will create a function with the same name as the mapping which will allow us to lookup the key outside the contract
    // no data is ever hidden in a smart contract deployed on a public chain and using `private` will not hide data in any way.
    mapping(address => uint8) public choices;
    
    
    function enroll() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function play(uint8 choice) external {
        // check that the move is valid
        require(choice == ROCK || choice == PAPER || choice == SCISSORS);
        // check that the player hasnt played the move already
        require(choices[msg.sender] == 0);
        // set the choice for the players address
        choices[msg.sender] = choice;
    }

  function evaluate(address alice, address bob)
        public
        view
        returns (address add)
    {
        // if the choices are the same, the game is a draw, therefore returning 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as the winner
        if (choices[alice] == choices[bob]) {
            return address(0);
        }

        // paper beats rock bob/alice
        if (choices[alice] == ROCK && choices[bob] == PAPER) {
            return bob;
            // paper still beats rock (played in opposite alice/bob)
        } else if (choices[bob] == ROCK && choices[alice] == PAPER) {
            return alice;
        } else if (choices[alice] == SCISSORS && choices[bob] == PAPER) {
            return alice;
        } else if (choices[bob] == SCISSORS && choices[alice] == PAPER) {
            return bob;
        } else if (choices[alice] == ROCK && choices[bob] == SCISSORS) {
            return alice;
        } else if (choices[bob] == ROCK && choices[alice] == SCISSORS) {
            return bob;
        }

    
    function pickWinner(address bob, address alice) public payable {
        if (evaluate(alice, bob) == bob) {
            bob.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
        if (evaluate(alice, bob) == alice) {
            alice.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
        players = new address[](0);
    }
    }        

        
        
    
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly enclosed the "evaluate" function. You need to move the curly brace in line 72 to line 61. Also, I think you have to make bob and alice addresses payable in the "pickWinner" function. Doing both things you'll have this:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 */
contract Game {

    uint8 constant ROCK = 0;
    uint8 constant PAPER = 1;
    uint8 constant SCISSORS = 2;
    address[] public players;

    // the public keyword will create a function with the same name as the mapping which will allow us to lookup the key outside the contract
    // no data is ever hidden in a smart contract deployed on a public chain and using `private` will not hide data in any way.
    mapping(address => uint8) public choices;
    
    
    function enroll() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function play(uint8 choice) external {
        // check that the move is valid
        require(choice == ROCK || choice == PAPER || choice == SCISSORS);
        // check that the player hasnt played the move already
        require(choices[msg.sender] == 0);
        // set the choice for the players address
        choices[msg.sender] = choice;
    }

  function evaluate(address alice, address bob)
        public
        view
        returns (address add)
    {
        // if the choices are the same, the game is a draw, therefore returning 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as the winner
        if (choices[alice] == choices[bob]) {
            return address(0);
        }

        // paper beats rock bob/alice
        if (choices[alice] == ROCK && choices[bob] == PAPER) {
            return bob;
            // paper still beats rock (played in opposite alice/bob)
        } else if (choices[bob] == ROCK && choices[alice] == PAPER) {
            return alice;
        } else if (choices[alice] == SCISSORS && choices[bob] == PAPER) {
            return alice;
        } else if (choices[bob] == SCISSORS && choices[alice] == PAPER) {
            return bob;
        } else if (choices[alice] == ROCK && choices[bob] == SCISSORS) {
            return alice;
        } else if (choices[bob] == ROCK && choices[alice] == SCISSORS) {
            return bob;
        }
    }
    
    function pickWinner(address payable bob, address payable alice) public payable {
        if (evaluate(alice, bob) == bob) {
            bob.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
        if (evaluate(alice, bob) == alice) {
            alice.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
        players = new address[](0);
    }
           

        
        
    
   
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have another question: why does this code below check that the player hasn't played a move already? 
It seems to me that the choice could be either 0, 1, or 2, for R, P, or S, so why is the code requiring that the choice be equal to 0. 
// check that the player hasnt played the move already
        require(choices[msg.sender] == 0);

Comment: I'm not an expert in Solidity, but I think that section of the code is simply wrong. If you call "choices" for ANY address that hasn't played, you get 0, that's because the way mappings work in solidity (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/types.html#mappings). So, line 31 is checking that value is 0 to see if that value has changed. But that's just wrong, because the person could have chosen ROCK (value 0). You can even try playing ROCK multiple consecutive times and the contract allows it but you can only play PAPER or SCISSORS once. That seems like an undesired behavior if you ask me

Comment: no problem, seems like you're pretty good to me! would you agree with this logic though: 
this line of code: 
 require(choices[msg.sender] == 0); 
actually comes before this line in the play function: 
  choices[msg.sender] = choice;
so, even if the player chose 0, that won't get added to the choices mapping until the end of the function after the require statement, so setting the require statement to be equal to 0 initially is actually okay

Comment: Yes, I agree that require(choices[msg.sender] == 0 should come before choices[msg.sender] = choice; that way you won't modify choices for the given address unless the person hasn't played yet. The point of that "require" is exactly that. But the problem is that ROCK = 0, so you can pass that line of code if: 1. The person hasn't played, OR 2. The person played ROCK. So, the logic is good if you change ROCK for some other value, like ROCK = 3

Comment: ahhh I finally understand what you're saying! Because no matter what the function will require an input choice initially. Thanks sir